# search csv for multiple strings in column a in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, match, multiple-columns

I have a sample.csv file

```
#Period,Account,Entity,Year,Version,Currency,HSP_Rates,Scenario,Data
Apr,1,9,FY22,F,L,H,And,2
Apr,1,9,FY22,F,L,H,And,2
Apr,1,9,FY22,F,L,H,OR,2
```

here i want to get output csv file where scenario only equals to AND

```
#Period,Account,Entity,Year,Version,Currency,HSP_Rates,Scenario,Data
Apr,1,9,FY22,F,L,H,And,2
Apr,1,9,FY22,F,L,H,And,2
```

i have written code which is not giving required output

```
$csvRaw = Get-Content -Path 'D:\sample.csv' -Raw 
$Csv = $CsvRaw.TrimStart('#') | ConvertFrom-Csv
$NewCsv = $csv | ForEach-Object {
[PsCustomObject]@{
    Period    = $_.Period
    Account   = $_.Account
    Entity    = $_.Entity
    Year      = $_.Year
    Version   = $_.Version
    Currency  = $_.Currency
    HSP_Rates = $_.HSP_Rates
    Scenario  = $_.Scenario | where {$_.Scenario -match "And" }
    Data      = $_.Data
} }
$OutCsv = ($NewCsv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation).TrimStart('"#')
# Converting back to CSV surround everything with double quotes. # We need to insert back the hash sign for the #period header$OutCsv[0] = """#" + $OutCsv[0]
$OutCsv | Out-File 'D:\sample_1.csv'
```

Comment: Why use a loop at all?  Simply do `$NewCsv = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Scenario -eq 'And' }`

Comment: Hi..is there a way to export that file into csv file ..i mean..i want to use only export-csv not out-file...which is not working for me...output csv which i got from out-file not working..even i have used -encoding ascii

Comment: `$NewCsv | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\yourfile.csv -NoTypeInformation'`

Comment: i have tried this..but not working

Comment: `$csv = import-csv -path "D:/sample.csv"
$NewCsv = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Scenario -eq 'And' } |
export-csv "D:/a/sample.csv" -Notypeinformation `

Comment: So, what is _"not working"_ ? Is there no directory `D:\a` or ???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax issue in the construction of the `[PSCustomObject]`.
Try replacing:

```
$NewCsv = $csv | ForEach-Object {
[PsCustomObject]@{
    Period    = $_.Period
    Account   = $_.Account
    Entity    = $_.Entity
    Year      = $_.Year
    Version   = $_.Version
    Currency  = $_.Currency
    HSP_Rates = $_.HSP_Rates
    Scenario  = $_.Scenario | where {$_.Scenario -match "And" }
    Data      = $_.Data
} }
```

With:

```
$NewCsv = $csv | ForEach-Object {
[PsCustomObject]@{
    Period    = $_.Period
    Account   = $_.Account
    Entity    = $_.Entity
    Year      = $_.Year
    Version   = $_.Version
    Currency  = $_.Currency
    HSP_Rates = $_.HSP_Rates
    Scenario  = $_.Scenario
    Data      = $_.Data
} } | Where { $_.Scenario -match "And" }
```

Which - as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) commented - is basically the same as:

```
$NewCsv = $csv | Where { $_.Scenario -match "And" }
```

Also, if you're using Powershell 6+, you may take advantage of the `-UseQuotes` parameter from the [`ConvertTo-CSV` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.2) to remove the quotes from the output.

Comment: Nice! I also tried your `$OutCsv[0] = '#' + $OutCsv[0]` to retrieve the first row and it's working fine. If it was helpful, may I ask you to accept the answer? :)

Comment: if possible can u suggest simple solution for my issue..without removing # or adding # and have to use import-csv and export-csv in code